# Android Studio - get path of other package through code

Tags: android, path, root

I have an app called `ExampleApp`. From that app's code I want to get the path of `/data/data/com.differentapp/databases` and delete all files from that folder. Seems like I can only access the path of `ExampleApp` (for example `/data/data/com.ExampleApp`) & the path of an external SD card, like in this example:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/sdcard" + "/recordings" + "/music recordings");

        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int j = 0; j < children.length; j++)
                new File(dir, children[j]).delete();
        }
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: "From that app's code I want to get the path of /data/data/com.differentapp/databases and delete all files from that folder" -- this is not possible, except on rooted devices.

Comment: Deinstall that app then Android does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t acces to the code of a different app from an app code.

Imagine that your app is being used by a person who does not have access to the code of your other application. How could your application access that code?

Comment: I don't want to access the code of a different app. I want to access the path of a different package and get the files' list.